# How to migrate this part of Oracle stored procedure to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "ORG_ORGANISATION_RECURSIV_V" ("NLEVEL", "CORGANISATION_TYP_LEVEL", "CORGANISATION_TYP_PATH", "CORGANISATION_TYP_PATH_ID", "NID_ROOT", "NDEBITOR_KOMPOSITUM", "NID") AS 
  SELECT LEVEL AS nLEVEL,
       lpad('.', LEVEL, '*') || o1.corganisation_typ corganisation_typ_level,
       sys_connect_by_path(o1.corganisation_typ, ',') corganisation_typ_path,
       sys_connect_by_path(o1.nid, ',') corganisation_typ_path_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT nid AS nid_root,
       o1.ndebitor_kompositum,
       o1.nid
  FROM org_organisation o1
CONNECT BY PRIOR o1.nid = o1.ndebitor_kompositum
ORDER SIBLINGS BY corganisation_typ DESC;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is part of a stored procedure? It doesn't at all look like one. This is a view on a recursive query. Use the standard SQL syntax for recursive queries in PostgreSQL instead of Oracle's proprietary `CONNECT BY`.

Comment: sorry, yes this is a view